# Is there a way to stop an animation just before contact between bodies in spritKit ?

Tags: sprite-kit, collision-detection, skphysicsbody, skphysicscontact

I have a SpriteKit animation where two bodies enter in contact at high speed. Unfortunatly if I use the didBeginContact Method, the two bodies are already overlapping a little when I stop the animation. I would like to stop the animation before the contact occurs, something like a willBeginContact method. Is there a way ? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no `willBeginContact` method available. Your question is a bit unclear to me, but if you are talking about moving animation, you can make a physics body of a node, a bit bigger (so you will have a contact detected, but the sprites will not overlap).

Comment: Also, `usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true` might be helpful when dealing with fast moving objects.

Comment: didBeginContact happens before the drawing occurs, so you can move your sprites in this stage so that they are not overlapping

Comment: @Whirlwind,  not sure if making the physics body larger will help with fast moving objects, if a sprite moves 8 points a frame, but the padding of the body is only 3, an overlap will happen.  Not sure if `usesPreciseCollisionDetection` will provide the data for the exact colision point

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Correct. It will not help with insanely fast moving objects. I assumed that OP keeps speed at normal level (means, all contacts end up detected) and that overlapping is minimal. So in that case, I proposed using `usesPreciseCollisionDetection` as a last resort.

Comment: Another thing is you can enable collision,  this should not allow overlapping

Comment: @KnightOfDragon I'm not sur enabling collision would change something. From one frame to the other the engine would assume a contact or a collision only when the two bodies overlap at least a little. The difference should be that the collision detection would move one of the bodies so that the overlapping is no more. I would like to prevent the overlap and stop the animation just before it occurs. Thanks again.

Comment: @Whirlwind thank you for your comments and your help.